# How to across JTextField to next JTextField by hit Enter

Tags: java, swing

When select check box to set enable(false) on second text field and hit enter need to focus at third text field
if not select any check box then hit ENTER it can be focus on text field as flow.
I should add any code or how can I make it work

My GUI:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE997.png]

```
private void chk1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // Set action perform for check box:
    if(chk1.isSelected()){
        p1.setEnabled(false);
    } else{
        p1.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

private void chk2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // Set action perform for check box:
    if(chk2.isSelected()){
        p2.setEnabled(false);
    } else{
        p2.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

private void chk3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // Set action perform for check box:
    if(chk3.isSelected()){
        p3.setEnabled(false);
    } else{
        p3.setEnabled(true);
    }
} 

private void p_numKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        p1.requestFocus();
    }
}

private void p1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        p2.requestFocus();
    }
}

private void p2KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        p3.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question and post a [mcve]. It looks to me like you are adding an `ActionListener` to each `JTextField`. Is that correct? It also looks like you are implementing `KeyListener` as well. You should post code that I can copy and run and which will display your GUI. Then write in the question what you are trying to do and where it doesn't work the way you want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [the Focus Subsystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html). This is responsible for the order in which components are getting focus when you press a focus traversal key. For example you can define what is the order of the components to get focus, and also add the check to transfer focus only to enabled components. What you also seem to want to do is to add the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key as a focus traversal key (ie when pressing it, the focus will be transfered to another component - according to the current focus traversal policy). All this can be done via the focus subsystem.

The following code seems to do what you are asking, by utilizing the focus subsystem:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.DefaultFocusTraversalPolicy;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FocusHopSystem {
    
    public static class AbsoluteFocusTraversalPolicy extends DefaultFocusTraversalPolicy {
        private final Component[] comps;
        
        public AbsoluteFocusTraversalPolicy(final Component... comps) {
            this.comps = comps.clone();
        }
        
        private int indexOf(final Component comp) {
            for (int i = 0; i < comps.length; ++i)
                if (comps[i] == comp)
                    return i;
            return -1;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getComponentAfter(final Container aContainer, final Component aComponent) {
            final int aIndex = indexOf(aComponent);
            if (aIndex < 0)
                return null;
            for (int i = 1; i < comps.length; ++i) {
                final Component after = comps[(aIndex + i) % comps.length];
                if (after != null && after.isDisplayable() && after.isVisible() && after.isEnabled())
                    return after;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getComponentBefore(final Container aContainer, final Component aComponent) {
            final int aIndex = indexOf(aComponent);
            if (aIndex < 0)
                return null;
            for (int i = 1; i < comps.length; ++i) {
                final Component before = comps[(aIndex - i + comps.length) % comps.length];
                if (before != null && before.isDisplayable() && before.isVisible() && before.isEnabled())
                    return before;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getFirstComponent(final Container aContainer) {
            for (int i = 0; i < comps.length; ++i) {
                final Component first = comps[i];
                if (first != null && first.isDisplayable() && first.isVisible() && first.isEnabled())
                    return first;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getLastComponent(final Container aContainer) {
            for (int i = comps.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                final Component last = comps[i];
                if (last != null && last.isDisplayable() && last.isVisible() && last.isEnabled())
                    return last;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getDefaultComponent(final Container aContainer) {
            return getFirstComponent(aContainer);
        }
    }
    
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        final String text = "0";
        final int width = 12;
        
        final JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(text, width),
                         tf2 = new JTextField(text, width),
                         tf3 = new JTextField(text, width),
                         tf4 = new JTextField(text, width);
        
        final JCheckBox ck2 = new JCheckBox("jTextField2", true),
                        ck3 = new JCheckBox("jTextField3", true),
                        ck4 = new JCheckBox("jTextField4", true);
        
        final JButton save = new JButton("Save");
        
        ck2.addActionListener(e -> tf2.setEnabled(ck2.isSelected()));
        ck3.addActionListener(e -> tf3.setEnabled(ck3.isSelected()));
        ck4.addActionListener(e -> tf4.setEnabled(ck4.isSelected()));
        
        final JPanel frameContents = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 5, 5, 5));
        
        //First row:
        frameContents.add(new JPanel());
        frameContents.add(ck2);
        frameContents.add(ck3);
        frameContents.add(ck4);
        frameContents.add(new JPanel());
        
        //Second row:
        frameContents.add(tf1);
        frameContents.add(tf2);
        frameContents.add(tf3);
        frameContents.add(tf4);
        frameContents.add(save);
        
        //Make the other components unfocusable:
        for (final Component comp: new Component[]{ck2, ck3, ck4, save})
            comp.setFocusable(false);
        
        //Make frameContents the focus cycle root:
        frameContents.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
        
        //Install our FocusTraversalPolicy to the cycle root:
        frameContents.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new AbsoluteFocusTraversalPolicy(tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4));
        
        //Add KeyEvent.VK_ENTER key to the focus traversal keys of the frameContents:
        final Set forwardKeys = frameContents.getFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS);
        final Set newForwardKeys = new HashSet(forwardKeys);
        newForwardKeys.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0));
        frameContents.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, newForwardKeys);
        
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Focus traversal test.");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(frameContents);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        //Start focus on the first text field:
        tf1.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(FocusHopSystem::createAndShowGUI);
    }
}
```

In the above example, I am adding the key <kbd>ENTER</kbd> as an alternative focus traversal key, aside from <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

### Edit 1: It's even simpler...

As I found out, it's even simpler than the first sample code, and that's because the default focus traversal policy does what you are asking, ie allows only focusable-and-enabled components to gain focus and in the desired order. So we only need to make the unneeded components to non-focusable (ie the check-boxes and the button) and leave enabled the text-fields. Just add/set the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key as a focus traversal key and you are good to go:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FocusHopSystem2 {
    
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        final String text = "0";
        final int width = 12;
        
        final JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(text, width),
                         tf2 = new JTextField(text, width),
                         tf3 = new JTextField(text, width),
                         tf4 = new JTextField(text, width);
        
        final JCheckBox ck2 = new JCheckBox("jTextField2", true),
                        ck3 = new JCheckBox("jTextField3", true),
                        ck4 = new JCheckBox("jTextField4", true);
        
        final JButton save = new JButton("Save");
        
        ck2.addActionListener(e -> tf2.setEnabled(ck2.isSelected()));
        ck3.addActionListener(e -> tf3.setEnabled(ck3.isSelected()));
        ck4.addActionListener(e -> tf4.setEnabled(ck4.isSelected()));
        
        final JPanel frameContents = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 5, 5, 5));
        
        //First row:
        frameContents.add(new JPanel());
        frameContents.add(ck2);
        frameContents.add(ck3);
        frameContents.add(ck4);
        frameContents.add(new JPanel());
        
        //Second row:
        frameContents.add(tf1);
        frameContents.add(tf2);
        frameContents.add(tf3);
        frameContents.add(tf4);
        frameContents.add(save);
        
        //Make the other components unfocusable:
        for (final Component comp: new Component[]{ck2, ck3, ck4, save})
            comp.setFocusable(false);
        
        //Make frameContents the focus cycle root:
        frameContents.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
        
        ////Install the DefaultFocusTraversalPolicy to the cycle root:
        //frameContents.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new DefaultFocusTraversalPolicy()); //This is not necessary in this case.
        
        //Add KeyEvent.VK_ENTER key to the focus traversal keys of the frameContents:
        final Set forwardKeys = frameContents.getFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS);
        final Set newForwardKeys = new HashSet(forwardKeys);
        newForwardKeys.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0));
        frameContents.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, newForwardKeys);
        
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Focus traversal test.");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(frameContents);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        //Start focus on the first text field:
        tf1.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(FocusHopSystem2::createAndShowGUI);
    }
}
```

You may also read [*The AWT Focus Subsystem*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/FocusSpec.html).

Comment: Thanks for both solution and advised, it works on my GUI style.

Comment: Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the way the `Tab` key works by default. When you press `Tab` focus will move to the next enabled component.

If you want to duplicate this functionality for the `Enter` key then first you can create a custom `Action`

```
Action transfer = new AbstractAction()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Component c = (Component)e.getSource();
        c.transferFocus();
    }
};
```

By default the "Enter" key will invoke the `ActionListener` added to the text field. So, now you can add this `Action` to specific text fields:

```
...
textField1.addActionListener( transfer );
textField2.addActionListener( transfer );
```

Or you can replace the default Enter `Action` of all the text fields by adding your custom `Action` to the `ActionMap`:

```
...
ActionMap am = (ActionMap)UIManager.get("TextField.actionMap");
am.put("notify-field-accept", transfer);
```

Comment: So what are the advantages or disadvantages for each of the two solutions, or is it just a matter of different concepts being invoked?

Comment: @Snorik, It depends on your requirement. The first suggestion allows you to customize the Action for individual text fields. The second approach affects all text fields in the application. And the approach by gthanop will affect all components including the check box and button.

Comment: Thanks a lot for both solution, it's work and match my requirement but much better if can make more shortcode.

Comment: @SuratPh  This answer is different from the other answer in terms of requirements. If this answer meets your requirements then the other other doesn't. Your requirement was to only change functionality for the text fields, not for all components.