# How to allow Enter key to proceed to the next text field?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have 2 `JTextField` components and I want the typing to proceed to the next text field when Enter key is pressed. How to achieve this?

Comment: Either use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) or add an [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) to the `JTextField`.

Comment: Given the enter key is typically used in text fields to indicate 'process this information', using it to go to the next field would ***not*** be the 'path of least surprise' to the end user. Keep the tab key to navigate between text fields, and the enter key to do the job it is usually used for.

Comment: You are looking for the Focus Subsystem. Give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63227570/how-to-across-jtextfield-to-next-jtextfield-by-hit-enter) a try.